# Public Class not Accessible irrespective of the same Namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I can't instantiate a class in another folder in my project, even though they have the same namespace.

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
      public class MyFirstClass
      {
           MySecondClass myClass = new MySecondClass();
      }
}

namespace MyNameSpace
{
     public class MySecondClass {}
}
```

If I hover my mouse over the "myClass" variable I get the message:

> The type or namespace name 'myClass' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I cannot figure out why this isn't working. I've been stuck for hours.

Comment: Call the member something other than `class`?  That's a keyword in C#, using it as a member *of a class* seems to be inviting confusion.

Comment: `class` is a reserve word. use someother name for it.

Comment: I didn't actually use the word "class" I'm sorry I should've been more careful in my pseudo code.

Comment: @maximus009 - when I put the one code piece in one folder and the other in a different it compiles fine... Do you have any extra information you can say to help us solve it?

Comment: What is the build action for the file that contains the class that isn't recognized? And can you confirm they're in the same project?

Comment: Same project, yes. This is a website so it doesn't have a build action.

Comment: When you look at the properties of those cs files what do you see under Build Action?

Answer (score 1):

`class` is a [reserved keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx). Just rename the variable

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
      public class MyFirstClass
      {
           MySecondClass instance = new MySecondClass();
      }
}

namespace MyNameSpace
{
   public class MySecondClass
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome :).  Correct Nomenclature is always helpful.

Comment: I didn't actually use the word "class" I'm sorry I should've been more careful in my pseudo code.

Answer (score 0):

Infact, you can give a variable name that's also a reserved keyword if you want to.

Just add an `@`in front of the variable name which will  tell the compiler to ignore that it is also a keyword and treat it as a variable instead.

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
      public class MyFirstClass
      {
           MySecondClass @class = new MySecondClass();
      }
}

namespace MyNameSpace
{
     public class MySecondClass {}
}
```

Comment: I didn't actually use the word "class" for my variable, I'm sorry I should've been more careful with my pseudo code.